# Windows launcher shortcuts minimize my windows

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

I'm using Windows 11, and I often make use of keyboard shortcuts to navigate among open windows by using <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+`n` where `n` is a numeric key that corresponds to an application in my launcher at the bottom of my screen. For instance, I might press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to move focus to my text editor.

I find that when my desired window is *already* focused, pressing the keyboard shortcut minimizes the window, but I don't want that; I want the desired window to just stay focused. Here's an example of what I want:

When my web browser is focused, I can press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to focus my text editor. Then pressing <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> a second time should keep focus on my text editor without minimizing it. How can I configure my Windows 11 installation to support this behaviour?

Comment: I don't think you can. This is a core feature of windows. I don't even think something like an autohotkey script can capture the key either.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the need here.  1. It is presumably a mistake when you try to put the focus on a window that is already in focus. 2. You are presumably holding the `WinKey` when the window minimizes so why not just hit the `1` key again so that it maximizes and is back in focus?  Just trying to understand the problem space.

Comment: @BlindSpots I often struggle to tell which of my windows is in focus; it's faster for me to use my WinKey launcher and just start typing than it is for me to try to look at any particular part of the screen to figure out which window is focused. (I need to work on Windows now, having come from Linux, and I've been at this for a month, and this part of the adjustment remains a struggle.)

Comment: Have you tried `alt`+`tab`?

Comment: Read your explanation, still don't know why `WinKey`+`1`+`1` is laborious.

Comment: Thanks, @BlindSpots, I'm just used to faster action where I don't have to receive visual input before I start executing commands or typing code.

Comment: I like to do things quickly too.  `WinKey`+`1` seems to work for you, and in cases where you have the window already in focus the window will fly down and you'll simply hit the `1` one extra time. Is there another dimension to this that is unclear to me?

Comment: No other dimension.